# Javascript weird dot operator syntax

Tags: javascript, numeric, literals

In Chrome console, also test in edge and firefox

```
5.toFixed(2);
```

get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

in chrome.

> SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

in firefox.

> Expected ';'

in edge.

But code below

```
5.1.toFixed(2);
(5).toFixed(2);
```

is ok in all three browsers above.

Comment: because numbers ... try `5..toFixed(2)` as well ...

Comment: [_Return a String containing this Number value **represented in decimal fixed-point notation** with fractionDigits digits after the decimal point._](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.5)

Comment: That code is ambiguous as to what the first "." stands for, either a decimal point for a float or a dot property separator. It is interpreted as a decimal point, so the identifier *toFixed* is unexpected.

Comment: @Tushar—it doesn't get that far, it's a syntax error.

Comment: As an aside, on those rare occasions when I see something like `5.1.toFixed(2)` in code my response is "Why?" Why not simply `"5.10"`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the JavaScript parser assuming the dot in for example `5.toFixed(2)` belongs the number literal. (As in `5.`, which is a valid number literal.) This is because JavaScript parses (at least number literals) greedily.

If you do `(5).toFixed(2)` however, it is clear to the parser what you want (the dot clearly is not a part of the number literal).

Same with `5.1.toFixed(2)`. The second dot clearly cannot belong to the number literal, so the parser has a better time with it.